# Querying Colorspace in a Database

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-queryset

I'm using Django and have a MySQL database filled with arbitrary RGB colors. The RGB values are stored as Integers.

```
| Name  | R | G | B |
+-------+---+---+---+
| Green | 0 |255| 0 |
| Cyan  | 0 |255|255|
| ...   | . | . | . |
| Foo   |123| 45| 2 |
| ...   | . | . | . |
```

Given an arbitrary RGB value `(a,b,c)` I want to calculate what colors in the database are "close to" `(a,b,c)`. I'll predefine what "close to" means in my query but for now let's call it `x`.

You can think of the RGB color space as a three dimensional space with colors as points in that space. So `(a,b,c)` and `x` define a sphere in that space with a center point `(a,b,c)` and radius `x`.

Pythagorus tells us that the following is true for all of the points within this sphere:

```
(R-a)**2 + (G-b)**2 + (B-c)**2 <= x**2
```

I would like to translate this into a valid Django Query. And, failing that, a MySQL query.

I'm no MySQL expert but I have some suspicions that the Django Query syntax may be very limiting in this context. Would writing a raw SQL query be the way to go here? Would it be better because the code would be more clear? Could it actually be faster/more efficient?

---

Django Color Model looks like:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    r = models.IntegerField()
    g = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
```

An example query:

```
c = (234, 23, 45)
x = 25

nearby_colors = Color.objects.filter(....) # Awesome-sauce
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who provided input, but I thought my solution was different enough from what was suggested that I should create my own answer.

```
def build_color_query(sphere_color_range):

    c = sphere_color_range[:3] # Sphere center
    r2 = sphere_color_range[3]**2 # Radius-squared

    # Use the "POWER" function is the database is MySQL
    if settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.mysql':

        color_query = """POWER((tcolor.r - %(a)s),2)
         + POWER((color.g - %(b)s),2)
         + POWER((color.b - %(c)s),2) <= %(r2)s""" % ({
            'a':str(c[0]),
            'b':str(c[1]),
            'c':str(c[2]),
            'r2':str(r2),
        })

    # Otherwise we use multiplication
    else:

        color_query = """(color.r - %(a)s) * (color.r - %(a)s)
         + (color.g - %(b)s) * (color.g - %(b)s)
         + (color.b - %(c)s) * (color.b - %(c)s) <= %(r2)s""" % ({
            'a':str(c[0]),
            'b':str(c[1]),
            'c':str(c[2]),
            'r2':str(r2),
        })

    # I had to include the `.filter(r__gte=0)` here in order for the 
    # right table joins to have been performed for me `extra` to work.
    # (It may not be necessary in this simplified version)
    return Color.objects.filter(r__gte=0).extra(where=[color_query])
```

Answer (score 2):

The django ORM way to create this query would be would be something like:

```
result = Color.objects.extra(
        where=['POWER(%d-a,2) + POWER(%d-b,2) + POWER(%d-c,2) <= POWER(%d,2)'  % (R,G,B,x)]
        ).all()
```

Which if you print the generated query with variables R=50, G=50, B=50, x=3 (ie. str(result.query)) you'd generate:

```
SELECT "whatever_color"."id", "whatever_color"."name", "whatever_color"."r",
        "whatever_color"."g", "whatever_color"."b" 
    FROM "whatever_color" 
    WHERE POWER(50-a,2) + POWER(50-b,2) + POWER(50-c,2) <= POWER(3,2)
```

Note that the POWER() function is mysql-specific though, so this is not database agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
select *
from color
where POW(R-a,2) + POW(G-b,2) + POW(B-c,2) <= POW(x,2)
```

where R,G,B are the columns, and you will supply values to replace, a,b,c,x

Some sample data to test

```
create table color(r int, g int, b int);
insert color values (200,50,200);
insert color values (0,50,200);
insert color values (0,50,20);
insert color values (150,150,200);
insert color values (200,50,0);
insert color values (50,50,50);
insert color values (40,60,40);
insert color values (50,50,101);  # 101-50 = 51 > 50 on the B-value
insert color values (50,50,100);  # just
insert color values (50,50,99);   # inside = ok
insert color values (40,60,40);
insert color values (70,70,70);
insert color values (85,80,75);  # 35 / 30 / 25 => 2750 > 2500
```

A query, 50 units from (50,50,50)

```
select *
from color
where POW(R-50,2) + POW(G-50,2) + POW(B-50,2) <= POW(50,2)
```

The output

```
"r";"g";"b"
"50";"50";"50"
"40";"60";"40"
"50";"50";"100"
"50";"50";"99"
"40";"60";"40"
"70";"70";"70"
```

Comment: Wow, really, that will work? I guess to say that the Django Query language is limiting is a massive understatement.

Comment: @Chris / of course you need to use the correct syntax, the `POW()` function and not the SQL-Server ^ operator!

Answer (score 0):

My brain is fried right now, so the exact syntax is a little off, but, assuming you have an index on R, G, and B, do three queries, one for each index, and join them together.

```
SELECT * FROM COLOR color
         JOIN (SELECT * FROM COLORS WHERE (color.R-a) < threshold)
         JOIN (SELECT * FROM COLORS WHERE (color.G-b) < threshold)
         WHERE (color.B-c) < threshold
```

You need to make sure you the type of join that doesn't allow null values. I forget if that works or not.

But someone with better sql experience and more sleep than I can build upon this :-)